# how to insert zoom , sattelite image and trafic opption on google map in php and javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have to display google map in my php code.

for that i have used the following code,

function addAddressToMap(response) {

```
     map.clearOverlays();
     if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) {
       alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode that address");
     } else {
       place = response.Placemark[0];
       point = new GLatLng(place.Point.coordinates[1],
                           place.Point.coordinates[0]);
     map.setCenter(new GLatLng(place.Point.coordinates[1],place.Point.coordinates[0]), 13);
     marker = new GMarker(point);
     map.addOverlay(marker);
 marker.openInfoWindowHtml('<b>City:</b> ' + document.getElementById('city').value);
     }




    }
```

and this code runs perfectly and giving me map also and writenow i m unable to show that output.

but i want to place zoom, sattelite image and traffic option on that map just like google maps.

any help?

Comment: huh? That looks like javascript to me... What has this got to do with PHP?

Comment: ya that's true but it actually done in php page. and i have some output there also which i have not mentioned here.

Comment: So it is actually a php page that outputs the javascript. You should make it clear as the javascript portion and the php portion is complete seperate and do not affect each other.

Comment: do you have answer of my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this in Google API's documentation

```
function initialize() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"))
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
      }
    }
```

I think you need to call the addControl method on yours also.

see http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/control-simple.html